# Fixed div overlapping content?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with position: fixed but when I scroll the window at the bottom the div overlaps with the footer. I dont want the div to overlap with the footer.

What changes should I make in css to overcome that.

`a.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contain">
            <div class="data1"></div>
            <div class="data"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`a.css`

```
.contain {
    margin-bottom: 35rem;
}
.data {
    background-color: red;
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: -33%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 600px;
}

.data1 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 60%;
    background-color: black;
}

.footer {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please share your code, it will help to understand the problem.

Comment: @bart Added my code

Comment: Just augment the negative `margin-top` to `34%`?

Comment: sorry i meant `-34%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `fixed` with `sticky`. Please modify the code like below and see that works for you:

```css
.contain {
/*     margin-bottom: 35rem; */
}
.data {
    background-color: red;
    border: 4px solid black;
    width: 30%;
    bottom: 30%;
    position: sticky;
    height: 300px;
}

.data1 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 60%;
    background-color: black;
}

.footer {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. The portion that I want fixed is now scrolling with the page, like I didn't want.

Comment: Can you post your code .. or may be a working link?

Comment: can i know what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you see the pen? The scrolling of the box underneath is acceptable you think?
The buttons are not clickable. I am trying to achieve is a neat and presentable display of information with working buttons. Where the button div stays fixed and the lower div scrolls.

Comment: Yes. That's it. Thanks. Another friend had me build multiple divs. Your solution is as simple as I thought it could be. Will have to study it to understand what you did.